# C# and WinForms: 'Integrity' of Form.Show() call

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the UI thread I have a piece of code that goes like this:

```
SomeForm form = new SomeForm();
(...)
form.Show();
```

SomeForm class particularly has a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instance as a member that is being initialized by auto-generated code of `InitializeComponent()` that looks like this:

```
this.UploadStatusTimer.Enabled = true;
this.UploadStatusTimer.Interval = 1000;
this.UploadStatusTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.UploadStatusTimer_Tick);
```

`form.Show()` will in the end raise `Form.Load` event that is being handled by `SomeForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

My question is: is there a possibility that `UploadStatusTime_Tick` was being processed before `SomeForm_Load`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking is "can it take longer than one second from the time I construct my form for the Load event to fire?"

Beyond the theoretical answer of "yes, this is always possible" it really comes down to how long (...) takes in your example code.  The timer is going to start counting down as soon as Enabled is set to true (when it is constructed).

It's important to note that UI interactions are processed via a message pump. So thinking of the winforms timer, the timer itself is off running in the background (outside of .net even; it is using the native windows timer) and when the timer expires it sends a message to your application, which then queues a message on the message pump that says "hey, timer tick happened."  Same thing applies to your form load event, it is triggered via a message on the message pump.  So if the timer expires before the form "loads" then the timer message will be in front of the 'form load' message on the queue and get processed first.

If you're interested in learning more, there many articles or stack overflow questions on the winforms message pump (or message loop as some may call it).

Comment: Everything being run in the UI thread, I expected that all of my statements in the current path of execution (i.e. form creation, `.Show()` and `SomeForm_Load`) would be completed by the time 'external' event, like timer tick, would have the right to be processed. So it's not that simple?

Comment: @MichałCzerski I've updated my answer with a very brief explination of the winforms message pump, which explains why the call to .Show() is not a single, uninterrupted execution all the way to the Load event.

Answer (score 4):

`InitializeComponent()` is called by the constructor of the Form, so it is possible that `UloadStatusTimer_Tick` is already called, before you call `form.Show()`.

If you want the timer to start after you call `form.Show()`, set `UploadStatusTimer.Enabled = false` in the designer, override `OnShow` and use this method to set `this.UploadStatusTimer.Enabled = true`.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the timer does NOT go off before `Form_Load`, disable it in the designer and call `timer.Start();` in the `Form_Load` event.

To ensure that it does go off before `Form_Load`, move the code in the `timer_Tick` function to a central method and call that from the constructor.